# oracle sql query question(grouping by 2 columns)

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table called `testgroup` in my database, which is like following:

```
I                      J                      
---------------------- ---------------------- 
1                      a                      
1                      a                      
2                      a 
1                      b                      
1                      c                      
2                      b      
3                      d    
2                      b 
2                      b
3                      d
```

Now, I want the result as below:

```
I                      J                      COUNT(J) in I 
---------------------- ---------------------- ----------------------
1                      a                      2                    
2                      a                      1
1                      b                      1
1                      c                      1
2                      b                      3    
3                      d                      2
```

...where `count(j) in I` is the number of each J related to the I.
For example: with `I = 1`, there are 2 `a` in column J, so the third column would be equal 2.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
select I, J, count(*) as JinI
FROM atable
GROUP BY I, J
```

Answer (score 10):

In fact the question is about counting I and J pairs:

```
select I, J, count(*) from tblName group by I, J
```